# Как не путать окна с ssh подключениями?

Tags: linux, cmd, ssh

Часто приходится иметь как минимум 3 окна с ssh подключениями (local, dev, prod) глаз замыливается и часто пробегают мурашки когда кажимаешь энтер. Как вы с этим боретесь, может можно изменить цвет фона или что еще? (ubuntu)

Comment: `tmux`.  Каждое подключение имеет свой цвет оформления и свой цвет курсора.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую Termius (и мобильная версия есть - но не синхронизируется в бесплатном тарифе) - там удобно много подключений иметь. Для prod тему другого цвета настроил - там это в 1 клик делается.